# Spacing issues in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-float

I keep having some weird spacing issues between divs in Firefox when compared to Chrome. Firefox is computing the height of an element greater than the content inside of it.

I am already using a CSS Reset.

Tried changing `box-model`, `float`, `display`, `margin`, `padding` and nothing produces any results.

Seen in Firefox:

[image: When viewed in Firefox]

Seen in Chrome:

[image: When viewed in Chrome]

Comment: is it possible to see the code online somewhere? or replicate your css and html in a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: give some code please, and better in a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760396/chrome-automatic-shift-of-web-elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width for this div which is under  CARD NUMBER line. Set it upto 290px.

```
<div class="pure-u-sm-1 pure-u-8-24 reason"></div>
```

Comment: Setting a fixed width breaks the responsiveness. Any other methods?

Comment: you can set max-width as well

Answer (score 0):

`width:inherit` on the end div worked here.

Answer (score 0):

The grid system you have chosen uses `flexbox` for WebKit and `inline-block` for Firefox, with not totally removed whitespace characters between blocks. The current version of Firefox supports flexbox (unprefixed), too, so you can add

```
display:flex;
flex-flow:row wrap;
```

to `.pure-g` to get the same display in Firefox as in Webkit.

Also, this grid systems relies on magic constants like `-0.43em` (supposed to be the width of the whitespace character but not equal to it in any of the popular fonts). It's better not to rely on such things, so try other grid systems with no such 'dark magic'.

Comment: Maybe this example helps: http://jsfiddle.net/XeVFP/5/ It uses 'magic' only for old browsers and `flexbox` for any browser that `@supports` it.